# Is there any algorithm good at pick special category?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

When I see machine learning, specially the classification, I find that some algorithm are designed to classify , for example, the Decision tree, to classify without the consideration as described next:

For a two categories problem, category A and B, people are interested in a special one, for example the category A. For this case, assume that we have 100 for A and 1000 for B. A good classify may have a result that mixed 100A and 100B as a part and let 900B another part. This is good for classify . But is there a algorithm can pick, for example , 50A and 5 B to a part and 50 A and 995 B for another part. This may not so good as a view of classify, but if some one is interested in category A, I think that next algorithm can give a more pure A result so it is better.

In short, it means is there a algorithm can pure a special category, not to classify them with no bias?

If scikit-learn have included this algorithm, it is be better.

Comment: I wired that why some guys oppose it? Is the English reason or this question is too boring?

Comment: the question is not understandable at all

Comment: for example , decision tree may use entropy to classify data, but it doesn't consider people may favour to a special category . Maybe someone just want a good algorithm to pick this category out. Am I clear?

Answer (score 0):

Look into a matching algorithm such as the "Stable Marriage Problem."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you're asking for a machine learning algorithm that gives a higher weight to certain classes and are therefore proportionally more likely to predict those "special" classes.

If that's what you're asking, you could use any algorithm that outputs a probability of each class during prediction.  I think most algorithms take that approach actually, but I know specifically that neural nets do.  Then, you can either train the network on proportionally more data on the "special" classes, or manually post-process the prediction output (the array of probabilities of each class) to adapt the probabilities to your specification.

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply. I think "give a higher weight" is confused. Since sampe_weight = sample_weight*class_weight( at least in scikit-learn, it is that) . I think your way is trying to increase the weight of the special samples. If you do so, your train data may have more special category data proportion to other categories. I don't want to change the proportion of the data numbers in different categories.

Comment: You may want to try adding an example, something more concrete.  It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish.  In any case, I don't have any experience with scikit-learn, so I probably won't be able to help on anything specific to that tool.